# Entropie (information theory) calculation

Tags: entropy

I have a basic question about calculating the entropy of a split.

Assumed I have a set with 2 classes, yes and no. In this set I have 3 samples Yes and 2 samples No.

If I calculate the entropy of this set I obtain:

```
-(2/5)*(log(2/5)/log(2))-(3/5)*(log(3/5)/log(2))=0.9710
```

Now, that gets me confused. If the entropy would be zero I would have only samples of one class. If the entropy is 0.5 (for 2 classes) I have 50% Yes and 50% No samples. A value close to 1 tells me what exactly now?

A pointer please, I feel like I am not seeing the obvious here, but I don't understand when the entropy can reach 1?

Answer (score 0):

In a binary example such as yours, the entropy of the system will approach 1 if it is perfectly distributed to each of the possible outcomes (10 samples, 5 yes, 5 no).  The further from this even distribution the closer to 0.  You can see the binary entropy plot on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function).

More specifically the perfect distribution of the entropy sum is log2(numClasses).  So for 2 == log2(2) == 1.

Answer (score 0):

Entropy goes to 1 as the the number of observations with 50% probability of success in binomial distribution approaches to infinity.

For example,

```
c <- rbinom(100000,1,0.5)
freqsC <- table(c)/length(c)
entropyC <- -sum(freqsC * log2(freqsC))
entropyC
[1] 0.9999885
```

This is the entropy value with 100000 observations.

*And here is the entropy value with 100000000 observations.*

```
f <- rbinom(100000000,1,0.5)
freqsF <- table(f) / length(f)
entropyF <- -sum(freqsF * log2(freqsF))
entropyF
[1] 1
```

This is actually 0.999999969120836 but R gives it as 1.

Hope it helps.